# Flutter - FireBase compound query - does not display any result

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am trying to create compound query. I am always getting this 'No data available'.
It is strange, because there are data which match my query.
Please, can you help me to figure out what I am missing? Thank you

```
Future myQuery () async{

    final currentQuery = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Users')
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
        .collection('allTasks');

    Query nameQuery = currentQuery.where('status', isEqualTo: 'Inbox');
    Query nameValorQuery = nameQuery.where('important', isEqualTo: 'False');
    
    final snapshot = await nameValorQuery.firestore.collection('allTasks').get(); //('users/$userId').get();

    if (snapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) {
      print(snapshot.docs.first);
    } else {
      print (snapshot.docs.length);
      print('No data available.');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed your code. this should work. Hope it helps.

```html
  Future myQuery () async{
    final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
    final path = 'Users/$uid/allTasks';

    final currentQuery = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(path);
    Query nameQuery = currentQuery.where('status', isEqualTo: 'Inbox');
    Query nameValorQuery = nameQuery.where('important', isEqualTo: 'False');
    
    final snapshot = await nameValorQuery.get();

    final data = snapshot.docs;
    if(data.isNotEmpty){
      for(var i =0; i < data.length; i++){
        print(data[i].data());
      }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you.  If I want to display the result in a widget, should use return instead of print or should I pass data to a new view? Thank you

Comment: it depends on how you wanna use it. but most of the time, after getting the data, convert it to an object and then return it. the print is only to show you that you are getting the actual data. and its up to you to continue on how you wanna use the fetched data.

Comment: The idea is to allow the user to select criteria, then I call the compound query. Finally, I am supposed to show in a listview builder the result in a new view.